# [Zeppelin Apache][Angular] bind a form label with a angular variable

Tags: angularjs, apache-zeppelin

I'm going to explain my problem with `zeppelin` :

I want to use the Api in order to run a paragraph with params.
In fact i have succeeded to receive the data with

```
 ${variable} -> ([Dynamic form][1])
```

but angular can't interpret it.

The goal is to push data from the API of zeppelin in order to use its with `javascript`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! The question need some more details. 
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
With Spark interpreter you can receive data from api and store it into a dynamic form {toto} and use it with angular after a z.angularBind("name", "toto") in your spark code;
You can now use angular with your dynamic form. The synthax to use it is {{name}}.